# How to compare 2 lists without sorting the files and print data in ouput file keeping the order of one of the files

Tags: linux, list, command, match

I'm fairly new to linux and I wonder how I can combine the info of two files without sorting them and maintain the same order in the output as one of the files.

File 1: Name List with names repeated

C_AWD_1

C_AWD_1

C_AWD_358

C_AWD_358

C_AWD_358

C_AWD_99

C_AWD_99

C_AWD_3581

File 2: Name list + info separated by spaces (imagine C_AWD_1 -up to thousands- C_AWD_19897), each name is present once only.

C_AWD_1 Av. cot: 18.90

C_AWD_2199 Av. Cot: 20.80

C_AWD_358 Av. Cot: 198.56

C_AWD_3581 Av. Cot: 34.90

C_AWD_99 Av. Cot: 53.9

My desired ouput is obtaining the name list in the same order as File 1 having its corresponding "Av. Cot" numerical value next to the name separated by a tab. Thank you all in advance.

Output:

Name   Av. Cot

C_AWD_1  18.90

C_AWD_1   18.90

C_AWD_358   198.56

C_AWD_358   198.56

C_AWD_358   198.56

C_AWD_99   53.9

C_AWD_99   53.9

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be done with bash, if your second file contains exactly one line matching for every line in first file, this will work:

```
for line in $(cat file1); do
  line=$(grep "$line Av." file2)
  echo -e "$line\n" >> result
done
```

result:

```
$ cat result 

C_AWD_1 Av. cot: 18.90

C_AWD_1 Av. cot: 18.90

C_AWD_358 Av. Cot: 198.56

C_AWD_358 Av. Cot: 198.56

C_AWD_358 Av. Cot: 198.56

C_AWD_99 Av. Cot: 53.9

C_AWD_99 Av. Cot: 53.9

C_AWD_3581 Av. Cot: 34.90
```

Comment: Thank you very much Barjomet, that was very useful. Sorry I took a while to come back and let you know how I was doing, my thesis is too much of a distraction from the real world. Cheers.

Comment: Sure, if you need explanation, just ask. Actually this script can be shortened to oneliner — `for i in $(cat file1); do echo -e "$(grep "$i Av." file2)\n" >> result; done` , or on the other hand I can help to make it more specific, if there is additional requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know one of the more powerful scripting languages like perl or python? They're handy to know.  I would do this by loading the second file first and creating a hash map with the number following C_AWD_ as the key and the second number as the value. Then load the first file, and for each line look up the Av. Cot number that goes with the C_AWD number in the hash table, and print a corresponding line to the output.

Comment: Hi Realh, I have learned some python, but not enough to understand everything you suggest. (e.g hash map? .. I will google it). Thank you, so I guess that what I am trying to do is not possible by using a combination of linux commands?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to come back to this sooner. Actually it is possible by combining a few simple commands; @barjomet's script is short enough to type in on the command line if you didn't want to make it into a script file. I just didn't think of doing it that way. It could be slow if the files are very long though. Keep on learning python, being able to program gives you so much more power, especially in Linux. [Dive Into Python](http://www.diveintopython3.net/) (or [older version](http://www.diveintopython.net/)) might help. In python hash maps are called dictionaries, BTW.